# The Right Com Port (COM 7) is NOT Showing

Tags: clones, ch340

I just finished a camp for the arduino and the arduino uno that they gave us is not working with my computer even though everything was working on their computers. I am trying to upload with the same schematic, same Arduino, and the same code. It is not wanting to upload even after changing in the preferences to the same com Port. I have tried updating the drivers, but Windows 7 64 bit s saying this error message : This device cannot start. (Code 10) .  Also, there is an exclamation mark in the device manager but how hard I try, it doesn't go away.

Comment: -1 for improperly tagging this "arduino-uno" when what you actually have is a different design with a different USB serial solution.  You should accept your own answer for the ch340 based board you apparently have.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I could not use the arduino drivers because I am using a DCcduino uno that has a separate driver.

Comment: The DCcduino Uno clone uses a CH340 USB-serial chip. The Arduino IDE doesn't include the driver for that chip because none of the official Arduino boards use it. You need to download and install the driver from http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html

Answer (score 0):

> The Right Com Port (COM 7) is NOT Showing

It would appear that Microsoft Windows does not necessarily assign the same COM port for a given device from machine to machine.  It is usually up to the user to map which COM port is being used for which device.  Some applications which work with specific devices have been known to "search" for that specific device and automatically connect to the correct COM port.

> ...saying this error message : This device cannot start...

There is this Microsoft Web Page [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943104) about this error.

More specific help may be found [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting).  In particular, this passage looks promising:

> On Windows 7 (particularly the 64-bit version), you might need to go
>   into the Device Manager and update the drivers for the Uno or Mega
>   2560. Just right click on the device (the board should be connected to your computer), and point Windows at the appropriate .inf file again.
>   The .inf is in the drivers/ directory of the Arduino software (not in
>   the FTDI USB Drivers sub-directory of it).